# UILabel Clear Background

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

I've have a UIView which has several UIViews (view1-view10) and UILabels (label1-label3) as subviews.  label 2 is on top of view 3, and I have set label2's background color to clear, but I still get a white box around the label2 which blocks off some of my view 3.  How do I set it up so that the non text area is clear? I took a screenshot and posted here:

[image]

```
UILabel * newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[properties objectAtIndex:1] intValue], [[properties objectAtIndex:2] intValue], [[properties objectAtIndex:3] intValue], [[properties objectAtIndex:4] intValue])];
[newLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self addSubview:newLabel];
```

Comment: Setting the label's `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor clearColor]` is the proper approach. Show some relevant code.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the background color of the correct label or of all labels to clear? You might be viewing one that you aren't setting the background color of.

Comment: The one you show in your image is not the one you show the code for (you didn't set any text for the one you created in the posted code, so it wouldn't say "Enter text here!").

Comment: are you sure your label2 background is the culprit? check by adding colorful background colors to each of the views and labels (green, red, blue, yellow etc). You'll see who is the offender.

Comment: Hey @User2666897 Try this

Answer (score 3):

Also, be sure the opaque property of this label is NO.

Answer (score 0):

```
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:label];
```

Comment: It would be beneficial for future users to provide an explanation on how this answers the question.